# Replace() before html() and add "&" between two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, replace

Please check out this **[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/143/)**. It searches for strings that contain "Glucosamine". How can I strip out "Glucosamine" and add an "&" if it returns two strings, like this:

```
A Item
Sulfate
B Item
Sulfate & HCl
```

I got an undefined error using `.replace("Glucosamine","")` after `append`.

JSON:

```
[{"title":"A","Ingredient":"Glucosamine Sulfate,Vitamin C"},{"title":"B","Ingredient":"Vitamin D,Glucosamine Sulfate,Glucosamine HCl,Vitamin A"}]
```

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "text.json",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
            var title = item.title;
            var ingredients = item.Ingredient; 
              ingredients = ingredients.split(",");
           $.each(ingredients,function(i,ingredient){
            if (ingredient.indexOf("Glucosamine") >= 0) {
            $('.' + title+'glu').append('<h5>'+ingredient+'</h5>') 
             }
            });
        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

HTML:

```
<h3>A Item</h3>
<div class="Aglu"></div>
<h3>B Item</h3>
<div class="Bglu"></div>
```

Comment: Note sure if I'm understanding you.  Is this the effect you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/qs5HY/

Comment: You should call `ingredient.replace('Glucosamine', '')` before appending it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle, Thank you, that's what I want. But how can I check if it returns `Sulfate` and `HCl` together and adds an "&" between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

The problem is that you are trying (as far as I can tell) to use replace on the jQuery object like so:

```
// this will not work
$('.' + title+'glu').append('<h5>'+ingredient+'</h5>').replace("Glucosamine","");
```

The problem is that `replace()` is a function of the `String` object in javascript and there is no replace method in the jQuery object.  What you want to do is run `replace()` against the `ingredient` variable which is a string.

```
// this will work
$('.' + title+'glu').append('<h5>'+ingredient.replace("Glucosamine","")+'</h5>');
```

## Not answer

However, based on your latest comment, I don't believe this will actually help you.  Although it's unrelated to the actual problem you were having, I'll go ahead and quick put down here how I would approach what you are actually trying to do.  I would write your function this way:

```
    $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
        var title = item.title;
        var ingredients = item.Ingredient; 

        // this is good.  I  like the use of split here
        ingredients = ingredients.split(",");

        // here I would just filter the array.  Don't bother with indexOf.
        // You can just as easily use regex.  I've chosen to use an
        // actual regex pattern but you can also use something like this
        // just as easily: ingredient.match("Glucosamine");.  I just
        // chose to use regex for the sake of using i for case insensi-
        // tivity.  glucosamineBased is now an array of only the glucose
        // ingredients
        var glucosamineBased = ingredients.filter(function(ingredient){
            return ingredient.match(/glucosamine\s/i);
        });

        // now that we know which ones are actually glucose based, we
        // don't need to itterate through them.  Instead we can just jump
        // on combining them.  I use join which works the opposite as
        // split above.  After they are joined into one big happy string,
        // I strip out the glucosamine words.  Easy-peasy.  Just keep in
        // mind that you need g for global (don't just replace the first
        // one, but replace all instances of the pattern) and maybe i for
        // case insensitivity.
        $('.' + title+'glu').append('<h5>' +glucosamineBased.join(' & ').replace(/glucosamine\s/gi, '')+'</h5>');
    });
```

Hope this helps.

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/HANvQ/

(oops... forgot the demo)

Answer (score 1):

It's trickier to add the ampersand if the array contains more than one instance of the word "Glucosamine", but the following should do the trick:

```
$(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {
    var title = item.title;
    var ingredients = item.Ingredient;
    ingredients = ingredients.split(",");
    var string = '';
    $.each(ingredients, function (i, ingredient) {
        if (ingredient.indexOf("Glucosamine") >= 0) {
            ingredient = ingredient.replace("Glucosamine","");
            string += (string.length == 0) ? ingredient : " & "+ingredient;
        }
    });
    $('.' + title + 'glu').append('<h5>' + string + '</h5>')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wDyZd/2/